# Homogenous Containers with GROUP BY Part II

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have three tables, one of which I need to update:

```
CREATE TABLE Containers (
  ID int PRIMARY KEY,
  FruitType int
)
CREATE TABLE Contents (
  ContainerID int,
  ContainedFruit int
)
CREATE TABLE Fruit (
  FruitID int,
  Name VARCHAR(16)
)

INSERT INTO Fruit VALUES ( 0, 'Mixed' )
INSERT INTO Fruit VALUES ( 1, 'Apple' )
INSERT INTO Fruit VALUES ( 2, 'Banana' )
INSERT INTO Fruit VALUES ( 3, 'Cherry' )
INSERT INTO Fruit VALUES ( 4, 'Date' )

INSERT INTO Containers VALUES ( 101, 0 )
INSERT INTO Containers VALUES ( 102, 0 )
INSERT INTO Containers VALUES ( 103, 0 )
INSERT INTO Containers VALUES ( 104, 3 )

INSERT INTO Contents VALUES ( 101, 1 )
INSERT INTO Contents VALUES ( 101, 1 )
INSERT INTO Contents VALUES ( 102, 1 )
INSERT INTO Contents VALUES ( 102, 2 )
INSERT INTO Contents VALUES ( 102, 3 )
INSERT INTO Contents VALUES ( 103, 3 )
INSERT INTO Contents VALUES ( 103, 4 )
INSERT INTO Contents VALUES ( 104, 3 )
```

Let's assume this is the state of my database. Please note the `Fruit` table is used twice.  Once to describe the contents of the container, and once to describe if the container is meant to contain only one type of fruit or if it can be mixed.  Bad design IMO, but too late to change it.

The problem is that container 101 is incorrectly marked as MIXED when it should really be APPLE.  Containers with multiple contents of the same type are still homogenous containers and should be marked as such.

I know how to do a query that finds the containers that are incorrectly marked as mixed:

```
SELECT Contents.ContainerID
FROM Contents
INNER JOIN Containers ON
  Contents.ContainerID = Containers.ID AND
  Containers.FruitType = 0
GROUP BY Contents.ContainerID
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT Contents.ContainedFruit ) = 1
```

However, I don't know how to update every row in Container where this error has been made.  That's my question.

Comment: Note:  Obviously this is a gross simplification of my real database.  There are > 57,000 results from the `SELECT` query I posted, or else I'd just update it one by one :)

Comment: Please note that in your select statement HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT Contents.ContainedFruit ) should be equal to 1

Comment: Ya, you're right.  Changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do:

```
UPDATE Container
SET Container.FruitType = Proper.ProperType
FROM Container
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT Contents.ContainerID, 
  MAX(Contents.ContainedFruit) ProperType
FROM Contents
INNER JOIN Container ON
  Contents.ContainerID = Container.ID AND
  Container.FruitType = 0
GROUP BY Contents.ContainerID
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT Contents.ContainedFruit ) = 1
) Proper
ON Container.ID = Proper.ContainerID
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33d75/10)

Comment: Precisely what I'm looking for.  Well played, sir.  Well played.